# Android Studio: how to do an update through user-id without using a global static variable

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and to Android Studio.

I am trying to implement a ProfileActivity for a simple chat-project in which the user is able to update some rows in the User table of a SQLite Database through a simple profile-form after signing up and then signing in in the app.
That should appen through the method updateUser() through the query `db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(user.getId()) });` in the `DatabaseHelper` Class, as you can see here:

```
    /**
     * This method to update user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_CITY, user.getCity());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_AGE, user.getAge());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_SEX, user.getSex());
        // updating row
       db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(user.getId()) });

        db.close();
    }
}
```

Anyway I was getting all the time from the User-model an id = 0 and the update did not work.

Now, after many attempts, I found a (pseudo)solution providing a global public static integer variable "user_id" and accessing it directly in `ProfileActivity`. The table-update works fine now. Anyway I know that it is a very bad practice against the principles of data encapsulation, as you can see here:

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.chat_project.Sql;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.chat_project.Model.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";
    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_AGE = "user_age";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_CITY = "user_city";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_SEX = "user_sex";
    private User user;
    private Cursor userId;
    
    int rv = -1;
    public static int user_id;

    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_AGE +
            " INTEGER," + COLUMN_USER_CITY + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_SEX + " TEXT" + ")";
    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @return true/false
     */
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public boolean checkLoggedUser (String email, String password) {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";
        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};
    
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_id"));
            getLoggedUser(rv);
        }
        //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method to fill user_id with column index
     *
     * @param i
     */
    public int getLoggedUser(int i){
        //stores index of columns
        user_id = i;
        return user_id;
    }

    /**
     * This method to update user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_CITY, user.getCity());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_AGE, user.getAge());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_SEX, user.getSex());
        // updating row
        db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(user_id) });

        db.close();
    }
}
```

ProfileActivity.java

```
package com.example.chat_project.Activities;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView;

import com.example.chat_project.Model.User;
import com.example.chat_project.R;
import com.example.chat_project.Sql.DatabaseHelper;
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private final AppCompatActivity activity = ProfileActivity.this;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    private AppCompatEditText inputName;
    private AppCompatEditText inputAge;
    private AppCompatEditText inputCity;
    private AppCompatEditText inputSex;
    private AppCompatImageView profileImage;
    private AppCompatButton saveProfile;
    private AppCompatButton pickImage;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private User user;
    private String user_name, user_sex, user_city;
    private int user_age;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize views
     */
    private void initViews() {

        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        inputName = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        inputAge =   (AppCompatEditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserAge);
        inputCity=  (AppCompatEditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);
        inputSex = (AppCompatEditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserSex);
        profileImage = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfileImage);
        saveProfile = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveProfile);
        pickImage = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPickImage);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize listeners
     */
    private void initListeners() {

        saveProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize objects to be used
     */
    private void initObjects() {

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

        user = new User();

        inputName.setText(user.getName());
       
    }

 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonPickImage:
                /**
                 new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                 .title("set your image")
                 .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                 .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                 .itemsCallback((dialog, view, which, text){
                 switch (which){
                 case 0:
                 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                 break;
                 case 1:
                 profileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_profile_pic);
                 break;
                 }

                 })*/
                //insertImageToSQLite();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSaveProfile:
                postDataToSQLite();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is to post data to SQLite
     */
    private void postDataToSQLite() {

        user.setName(inputName.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText().toString().trim()));
        user.setSex(inputSex.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setCity(inputCity.getText().toString().trim());
        // here the static variable from DatabaseHelper is retrieved 
        user.setId(databaseHelper.user_id);
        databaseHelper.updateUser(user);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 
       
    }

}
```

How can I do in order to update the rows in the User-table without declaring a public static variable for the id?

Thank you very much in advance for every hint!

Comment: Ids can be either numbers or string.  The type has to be the same in the c# code as the database.  Make sure the ID type in the module matches the database type.

Comment: If the first code block is your previous (not working) approach, then it means your `user.getId()` was returning 0. How were you initializing your `user` object? You might want to load `user` from database instead of creating a new object every time

Comment: Also the `user_id` is not updated anywhere in the code you posted, you should post that part too.